# Convert alist to/from regular list in Elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Given the "everything's-a-list" homoiconic approach to code and data in Lisp, I'm having a hard time understanding how to manipulate alists in Emacs Lisp.  In particular, how can I convert an alist to an ordinary list of two-element lists, and vice versa?  It almost seems like alists are a special type of their own which can't be manipulated the way regular lists are.

Specific example:  I'm trying to bind a key in my `.emacs` file to create a frame of a certain size with a programatically generated name, as follows:

```
(make-frame '((name . "Blarg") (width . 80) (height . 24)))
```

This works fine as long as "Blarg" is a constant string, but because of the quote at the beginning of the alist, I can't put any code that evaluates to a string in place of "Blarg".  What I would like to do is build up a list by `cons`ing the symbols and integers for the width and height, then `add-list` the name on to the front, and pass the whole thing to `make-frame`.  But how do I convert the resulting data structure to an alist?

Specific answers on how to get `make-frame` to do what I want would of course be appreciated, but as my title indicates, I'm hoping for a more general explanation of how to manipulate alists and convert them to/from regular lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@wvxvw answered your general question. But note that what is described is *not* **converting** an alist to a list or vice versa.

And in general you do *not* need to do any such "conversion".  You can instead work directly with alists -- they are lists, after all.

Which brings me to the answer to your `make-frame` question, which is this, where `foobar` holds the name you want:

```
(make-frame `((name . ,foobar) (width . 80) (height . 24)))
```

or if you prefer:

```
(make-frame (cons (cons 'name foobar) '((width . 80) (height . 24))))
```

Comment: This is the backquote syntax, if dodgethesteamroller hasn't encountered it yet: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html

Comment: Voted both @Tom and you up.  Thanks!  But I still don't quite understand the "dot" notation for alists (which is why I thought it was necessary to convert them to/from ordinary lists).  Is that really just syntactic sugar for a two-element list?

Comment: dodgethesteamroller: Not quite. The dotted pair notation specifies car and cdr explicitly, and cdr *need not be another list*. For example, `'(width 80)` can be written as `'(width . (80 . nil))`. You should read `C-h i g (elisp) Dotted Pair Notation`

Comment: An alist is a list. The elements of the list are conses, but the list of conses is a true list, not a dotted list. IOW, the last cdr of the list of conses is nil. (In some Lisps an element of an alist can also be an atom. In Common Lisp, for example, it can be `nil` instead of a cons. In Emacs Lisp an element can be anything. In both languages, an element is ignored if it is not a cons.)

Answer (score 8):

Just my two cents on constructing alists:

```
(pairlis '(name width height)
         '("Blarg" 80 24))
;; => ((name . "Blarg") (width . 80) (height . 24))
```

Comment: That's very elegant.  Is the function `pairlis` part of the Elisp standard library or does it `require` something else?

Comment: It's part of `cl-lib`. You can `(require 'cl)` to use `pairlis`, or with the newer namespacing, `(require 'cl-lib)` to use `cl-pairlis` (which is the same function).

Answer (score 4):

```
(require 'list-utils)
(list-utils-flatten '((name . "Blarg") (width . 80) (height . 24)))
;; (name "Blarg" width 80 height 24)
```

`list-utils` is installable from MELPA.

Or using `loop`:

```
(loop for (head . tail) in '((name . "Blarg") (width . 80) (height . 24))
      nconc (list head tail))
;; (name "Blarg" width 80 height 24)

(loop for (head . tail) on '(name "Blarg" width 80 height 24) by 'cddr
      collect (cons head (car tail)))
;; ((name . "Blarg") (width . 80) (height . 24))
```

This is how I'd do it (requires `cl` library)

Comment: OK, that explains how to convert an alist to an ordinary list, but what about vice versa?

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller oh, yes, sure, missed that part. Edited the question.

Comment: You can replace `(car tail)` with just `tail` if you write `(head tail)` instead of `(head . tail)`.

Answer (score 1):

With [`dash`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list and tree manipulation library you can convert an alist into a flat list by transforming a dotted pair `(a . b)` into a 2-element list `(a b)`, then flattening the list, which is possible with [`-mapcat`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-mapcat-fn-list) (the 2 expressions below are equivalent):

```
(-mapcat (lambda (x) (list (car x) (cdr x))) my-alist)
(-flatten (-map (lambda (x) (list (car x) (cdr x))) my-alist))
(apply '-concat (-map (lambda (x) (list (car x) (cdr x))) my-alist))
```

In Haskell similar expressions (successively apply various functions to transform a list) would be more efficient and natural due to lazy evaluation.

So I want to use this answer as an opportunity to explore programming concepts a bit. What is it, when you traverse a list once and build some result based on its content (no matter what result)? It's a [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29)! The most primitive form of fold is one that takes a binary function and applies it to elements 1 and 2, then to result and 3, then to result and 4, and so on. So fold accepting `+` and list `[1,2,3,4]` becomes `((1+2)+3)+4`. `dash` has such kind of fold called [`-reduce`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-reduce-fn-list): `(-reduce '+ '(1 2 3 4)) ; => 10`

But this kind of fold is inflexible: a fold on a list of integers can only return an integer, not some arbitrary value. We need a more general fold, with better control. Such general fold uses an additional argument, called accumulator, which is used inside the binary function. On each iterator you can do anything with the list's element and the accumulator. The result of the function application becomes accumulator for the next iteration. In `dash` such fold is called [`-reduce-from`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-reduce-from-fn-initial-value-list). We take empty list as an accumulator, take each dotted pair in original alist one by one, then transform it into 2 new elements that we append to the accumulator inside our binary function. What could be easier?

```
(-reduce-from (lambda (acc x) (append acc (list (car x) (cdr x)))) '() my-alist)
```

But appending lists in such way is inefficient and idiomatic, because lists are implemented as singly linked lists in Lisp, so adding an element to the end or concatenating lists is O(n), the whole function works in O(n²). Lispers usually cons to the beginning of the list, but `-reduce-from` traverses the list left-to-right, that's why the result is going to be reversed. If only we could traverse the list right-to-left, so that we could the element, tranform it, and cons to the accumulator. Well, there's a function [`-reduce-r-from`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-reduce-r-from-fn-initial-value-list):

```
(-reduce-r-from (lambda (x acc) (cons (car x) (cons (cdr x) acc))) '() my-alist)
```

`-reduce-r-from` is the most efficient version, as it traverses the alist only once. Every time you need to build some list using a fold, chances are you need `-reduce-r-from`. Finally, what's great about the `dash` library is that it provides [anaphoric macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro) versions for functions that accept functions as arguments to get rid of `lambda` syntax:

```
(--mapcat (list (car it) (cdr it)) my-alist)
(-flatten (--map (list (car it) (cdr it)) my-alist))
(apply '-concat (--map (list (car it) (cdr it)) my-alist))
(--reduce-r-from (cons (car it) (cons (cdr it) acc))) '() my-alist)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `flatten` or `dash`. Lisp is somewhat functional (whatever that means). The point is, it has map functions. Most of what you try to achieve can be simply done with maps, reduce and filter (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html).

Here is flatten with a simple map function in standard library:

```lisp
(defun alist->list (alist)
  (mapcan (lambda (i)
            ;; see the last paragraph for more info
            (cons (car i)
                  (list (cdr i))))
          alist))
```

Also here a bonus:

```lisp
(defun alist->plist (alist)
  (mapcan (lambda (i)
            (cons (intern (concat ":" (car i)))
                  (list (mapcar 'intern (cdr i)))))
          alist))
```

Just a side note for curious souls, about alists:
An alist is basically, you guessed it, a simple list. NOTHING makes it special. You can do whatever operation you want on it. Logically however, it is a list that contains cons for each of its cells. As humans, we can use them as dictionaries so we read them as alists, otherwise, to Lisp, they are just simple plain good ol' lists just like anything else.

Knowing this, you'll realize why we need `list` function before `cdr` in `alist->list`. A cons is a list of 2 elements (much like characters arrays in C vs strings which are terminated by '\0'), but a list is a series of nested cons that are terminated by an implicit nil. This means that `(a b)` is `(a . (b . nil))`. So we must somehow transform `(a . b)` to `(a . (b . nil))` to be able to use `mapcan` for this purpose (read the docs for more info, quoting: "it returns a single list with all the elements of the results (which must be lists)").

Comment: That's unnecessarily complex though: `(cons x (list y))`, whatever the values of `x` and `y`, can simply be written `(list x y)`

Comment: @Numbra that's true, I just wanted to keep a symmetry between my explanation and code.
Thanks for mentioning again.